# React Native Mobile Wallpaper App Design Ideas

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to publish a react native app. It should be a wallpaper app. Now I am confused from where I should get the wallpapers and where should I store them to show them in my app and how can I set the dimensions of each wallpaper to be the same?

Haven't tried anything! Want to know